# Why is CSS grid showing two rows instead of one while trying to create a topnav menu? Is using grid for topnav a bad idea?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a topnav menu using grid. I have done it before and it worked fine. Now, after a few months I am trying it again and for some reason it is showing two rows instead of one. Also, columns and column gap is taking a lot of space for some reason (checked via f12 menu in chrome). I even tried adjusting the gap but no gain. It didn't happen for the first time.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font: 3.5em Trirong, "Times New Roman";
    font-weight: 500;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black, silver, white, white, white, silver, black);
}


/*main heading*/

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font: 2.5em Ubuntu, Calibri, Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/*reviews' main heading*/

.pmain {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Calibri Light";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}


/*main paragraph*/

.pfoot {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Calibri Light";
    font-size: 0.85em;
    text-align: justify;
}


/*footer*/

a.lmain {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*casual links*/

a.lmain:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.lmain:hover {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tnav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}

.tnav a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Calibri;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}


/*topnav links*/

.tnav a:visited {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tnav a:hover {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #f2f2f2;
}
<header>
  <h1>In-Depth Reviews</h1>
  <nav class="tnav">
    <a  href="index.html">Home</a> <br>
    <a  href="appreviews.html">App Reviews</a> <br>
    <a  href="apprating.html">App Rating</a> <br>
    <a  href="more.html">More</a> <br>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Remove those `<br>` tags in your nav code. They are each considered a grid item.

Comment: Oh, oh my God! how did I not notice it !! Thankyou very much for your input sir, sometimes you miss so simple things.